# Setup database without seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to setup my database with tables and such, but in certain cases I don't want my seed data to be loaded. I also don't want to delete or move my `db/seeds.rb` file every time I want to ignore my seed data.

Is there a way to perform the tasks of `rake db:setup` and ignore seed data?

Comment: `rake db:migrate` will create the tables without seeding.... is it what you mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. Just use the following two commands:

```
rake db:create
rake db:schema:load
```

What `rake db:setup` does is just creating the database (`db:create`), loading the data from `db/schema.rb` (`db:schema:load`) and then inserting the seed data (`db:seed`). You can do these steps separatly.